# C# Прием файла по сети

Tags: c#

Пишу клиент серверное приложение, в котором передаются файлы по сети. Собственно, само приложение работает хорошо, задачи выполняет, но когда я закрываю серверную часть,- программ виснет.

Вот код серверной части:

```
    NetworkStream myns;
    TcpListener mytcpl; 
    Socket mysocket;
    Thread myth;
    BinaryReader bb;

    void File_Receiver()
    {
        mytcpl = new TcpListener (7000);
        mytcpl.Start ();
        mysocket = mytcpl.AcceptSocket ();
        myns = new NetworkStream (mysocket);
        BinaryFormatter br = new BinaryFormatter ();
        object op;

        op= br.Deserialize (myns); // Deserialize the Object from Stream


        bb = new BinaryReader (myns);
        byte[] buffer = bb.ReadBytes(5000000);

        FileStream fss = new FileStream(@textBox1.Text + (string) op, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
        fss.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
        fss.Close();
        mytcpl.Stop();
        listBox1.Items.Add ("Successfully Saved to: " + textBox1.Text + (string) op);

        if (mysocket.Connected ==true)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                File_Receiver();
            }
        }
    }

 Также я определил, что зависание происходит при закрытии формы на соответсвующем обработчике этой формы:

   private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        myth.Abort ();
        mytcpl.Stop ();
    }
```

Как мне победить это проблему?

P.S. 
Да, нити запускаются как положено в обработчике формы и работают хорошо, пока не пытаюсь закрыть форму:

```
           private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        myth= new Thread  (new System.Threading.ThreadStart(File_Receiver)); 
                           // Start Thread Session
            myth.Start ();
         }
```

Comment: ! у вас одна единственная *нить* выполняющая бесконтрольную рекурсию внутри бесконечного цикла, условие `if (mysocket.Connected ==true)` проверяется **единственный раз перед запуском** этого бесконечного цикла -- кстати интересно, почему оно *виснет* только при попытке закрытия, а не сразу на входящем соединении :) -- ну, вы могли бы поставить условием продолжения цикла `while(isListen){File_Receiver();}` глобальный флаг `bool isListen=true;` который на закрытие формы будете первым делом снимать, а потом останавливать поток. Хотя КМК, бесконечный цикл и рекурсия друг друга дублируют...